# Run action if contains part of an attr value

Tags: javascript, jquery, if-statement, contains, attr

I have a input with this

```
attr('data-disabled-dates','12/02/2022; 13/02/2022; 14/02/2022; 15/02/2022; 10/03/2022; 11/03/2022; 16/02/2022')
```

And a const which results in tomorrow dynamically, so for this case the result is "16/02/2022"

Now i want to run action if it matches that tomorrow's date is within the attr data-disabled-dates.

So i tried this

```
if (jQuery(input).attr('data-disabled-dates') == '16/02/2022')
        { console.log('work') } else {
    console.log ('not') }
```

But it only gives me true if the whole sequence is exactly the same, that is, if I put "12/02/2022; 13/02/2022..." if it will give the result, but I only want it to be true if the value I am putting is inside

Comment: string a is found in string b if b.indexOf(a) is not equal to -1.

Comment: Use `string.includes(substring)` to search for a substring

Comment: Can you change the format of the attribute? jQuery `.data()` will parse JSON into an array.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use `String.includes()` or `String.split('; ')` to convert string to array and check if it includes the desired value.

```
if (jQuery(input).attr('data-disabled-dates').includes('16/02/2022')) { 
  console.log('work') 
} else {
  console.log('not') 
}
```

### Working example in vanilla JS

```js
const div = document.querySelector('#data');

const dates = div.getAttribute('data-disabled-dates');

if (dates.includes('16/02/2022')) {
  console.log('work')
} else {
  console.log('not')
}


// or
if (dates.split('; ').includes('16/02/2022')) {
  console.log('work')
} else {
  console.log('not')
}
```

```html
<div id="data" data-disabled-dates="12/02/2022; 13/02/2022; 14/02/2022; 15/02/2022; 10/03/2022; 11/03/2022; 16/02/2022" />
```

btw https://youmightnotneedjquery.com/

Answer (score 0):

`==` performs exact string matches, not substring matches.

You can use `.split()` to split the attribute value into an array, then use `.includes()` to test if the array contains the date.

```
if (jQuery(input).data('disabled-dates').split('; ').includes('16/02/2022')) {
    console.log("work");
} else {
    console.log("not");
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use indexOf to be greater than 0. IndexOf if you need to support IE.

```
var dataAttrValue = jQuery(input).attr('data-disabled-dates');
var date = '16/02/2022';
if (typeof dataAttrValue !== 'undefined' && dataAttrValue.indexOf(date)) > 0) { console.log('work');
} else {
console.log ('not');
}
```

OR

```
jQuery(input).is(“[data-disabled-dates*='16/02/2022']”);
```

But I suggest using JQuery Data to store and retrieve values from elements.